# My SQL: How to Return the count of distinct records (movies) where only movies shown on the 1st day of watching are showing

Tags: mysql, sql

I was trying to figure out how to return only the first date for records that have the same int ID.  To clarify, here is my table's columns:

ID int
name varchar(200)
movies varchar(200)
visit_date timestamp
day date

Let's say that I have 3 records with an ID int of 7, but their movies are different. What I want to do is count the number of distinct movies but only on the first day they started watching movies.

I have attempted the following SQL query in MySQL Workshop:

```
SELECT ID, name, movies, day, COUNT(movies) AS distinct_movies
FROM moviewatching 
WHERE day = (SELECT MIN(day) FROM moviewatching)
GROUP BY ID, name, movies, day
ORDER BY ID;
```

However, when I run this query, the table only returns the earliest date out of all day DATE records from the table when it should be returning the earliest date for each ID.  Can anyone explain what I need to do? I have already Google searched everywhere for this and couldn't find anything close to what I'm trying to do.

Here is the sample table of desired results:

```
ID  name      movies          day
4  Mike     Funky Monkey   04/22/18
6  orlando  The burrowers  08/26/22
6  orlando  Carnival Row   08/26/22
6  orlando  Beethoven.     08/26/22
6  orlando  The Standard   08/28/22
7  Mellany  Appalooza      09/30/22
```

But I only get the following:

```
ID  name      movies          day
4  Mike    Funky Monkey    04/22/18
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I want to do is count the number of distinct movies but only on the first day they started watching movies.

I would suggest window functions or two levels of aggregation.  Your question is a little vague but I think this is what you are describing:

```
SELECT ID, min_day, COUNT(DISTINCT movies) AS distinct_movies
FROM (SELECT mw.*,
             MIN(day) OVER (PARTITION BY id) as min_day
      FROM moviewatching mw
     ) mw
WHERE day = min_day
GROUP BY ID, min_day
ORDER BY ID;
```

Comment: @STANDARD_DEVIATIONX2 . . . This is returning the first row *per id* which is how I interpret your question.